# Como actualizar en un solo post multiples instancias - Django rest framework

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Tengo un array de objetos:

```
[
    {
      order: 4,
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      order: 2,
      id: 2,
    }
]
```

Donde **id** es la llave primaria y el order es el valor a actualizar, estoy enviando al server por post con axios :

```
this.axios.post('route-dispatchs/order/', this.ordsend)
   .then((response) => {
     console.log('success');
});
```

Y mi **Viewset**:

```
@list_route(methods=['post'], url_path='order')
    def order_dispatch(self, request):
        for data in request.data:
            self.queryset.filter(id=data['id']).update(order=data['order'])
        page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

En el cual filtro por el **id** y actualizo su respectivo **order** en un for. 
Pero me esta arrojando el siguiente error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Me esta faltando algo? ya que cuando mando solo uno `this.ordsend[0]` y le quito el for si llega actualizar el elemento.

Imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK luego de muchos intentos e investigación lo solucione de esta manera:
Primero desde axios lo envié desde un objeto:

```
this.axios.post('route-dispatchs/order/', {'sort': this.ordsend})
```

y en el server cambie el for por :

```
for data in request.data['sort']:
```

O sea ingrese al nombre del objeto y funciono :) espero le sirva a alguien.